# Error trying to generate Binding class for my Fragment

Tags: android, android-viewbinding

[image]

I have the following XML file which is a layout for my Fragment -

```kotlin
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<layout>

    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="15dp"
        tools:context=".fragments.DashboardFragment">

        <androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2
            android:id="@+id/fragment_dashboard_viewpager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    </LinearLayout>

</layout>
```

The `FragmentDashboardBinding` class is indeed auto-generated, but I can't use it -

```kotlin
class DashboardFragment : Fragment(R.layout.fragment_dashboard) {

    private lateinit var binding : FragmentDashboardBinding


    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        binding = FragmentDashboardBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
        return super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState)
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
    }

}
```

[image]

I get the error I picured at the top when trying to build the project, making it unusable

I am missing something. What could it be ?

I have wrapped my layout file with  as I should

I currently only need View Binding, and not data binding.

Comment: Can we use like this `Fragment(R.layout.fragment_dashboard)` ?

Comment: @ShaluTD Yeah, it is a new convenience way to reduce the need to write `onCreateView()` method.

Comment: Try my answer and let me know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please change your `fragment` as below:

```
class DashboardFragment : Fragment() {

    private lateinit var binding : FragmentDashboardBinding

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        binding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater, R.layout.fragment_dashboard, container, false)
        return binding.root
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
    }

}
```

`

Comment: Hi, where does this `DataBindingUtil` come from?

Comment: its from android.databinding.DataBindingUtil. You can use FragmentDashboardBinding instead.

Comment: I don't have access to android.databinding.DataBindingUtil at all and trying to use the FragmentDashboardBinding gives me the error "cannot access..." that I showed in the main post

Comment: import androidx.databinding.DataBindingUtil;

Comment: added `dataBinding {
        enabled = true
    }` in app gradle file